# Field strength is always closed?

Tags: electromagnetism

In electromagnetism, we can write the homogenous Maxwell equations succinctly as
$$dF=0$$
Where $F=E\wedge dt+B$ is the field-strength 2-form. However, it is a well-known fact that the field-strength 2-form is simply the curvature-form associated to some connection $\nabla$. Therefore,
$$F=dA$$
Where $A$ is the connection 1-form. Note that we always have these identities locally, even though $A,F$ may not be globally defined. So, **even with sources** (i.e. $j\neq 0$), we have the homogenous Maxwell equations (locally, of course): 
$$dF=0$$ 
Does this mean we can drop the adjective *homogenous* from the above equations?

Comment: If you write $F=dA$ then $dF=0$ is satisfied automatically and you do not need it anymore.

Comment: Hey Meng :) nice to see you here. The argument here is that $F=dA$ always locally, and so $dF=0$ irregardless of whether there are sources or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be in principle both magnetic sources and electric sources. Including these, one may write the full Maxwell equations as

$d \star F = \star j_E,$

$d F = \star j_M,$

where $j_{E,M}$ are the electric/magnetic currents, respectively (as I've written them they are 1-forms).

Since there are no experimentally observed magnetic charges (magnetic monopoles), the magnetic source term is typically dropped and the 2nd equation becomes $dF=0$. Because $dF=0$, $F$ may be locally written as $F=dA$ (this is due to the Poincare lemma).

So, to answer your question: Firstly, when you say even with sources $dF=0$, more specifically you mean even with electric sources, but not magnetic sources. Secondly, $dF=0$ is only half of the Maxwell equations. The other half is $d\star F = \star j_E$. So even though we may write $dF=0$ in the presence of electric-only sources, the equations are clearly not homogeneous.

Comment: $dF=0\Rightarrow F=dA$ is a consequence of the triviality of the first de Rahm cohomology group of $\mathbb R^4$, so unless clear from the context, it is in principle necessary to specify the ambient manifold.

Comment: Yes, it is important to specify the ambient manifold, but even if the ambient manifold is not $\mathbb{R}^4$, there could be sources present at which point $dF=0$ fails to hold, and secondly the Maxwell equations are more than simply $dF=0$.